# Linux (RHEL): How can I trigger that a process tries to reorganize its memory at a specific memory limit?

Tags: linux, optimization, memory, openshift, rhel

We are running a single process in an OpenShift environment and noticed that the longer the process is running the more memory it allocates until touching the upper limit of the POD which causes the process to be restarted.
Previously we have been thinking of a memory leak but when we run the same process in a Linux box with limited physical memory the operating system automatically frees unused pages once we are getting close to this limit and the memory consumption remains stable.
This is not the case in OpenShift as the machine behind has much more memory than defined in the YAML file so it reaches the defined limit before it can start to reorganize its memory.
There is also no other process running that could get the OS to lower the used memory of the primary process.

Is there a way to tell the OS to optimize the memory other than reaching the physical limit?

We have already tried to limit the users available memory with ulimit -m or ulimit -v but the first one is simply ignored and the second does not trigger the freeing of unused pages but just kills the process when it reaches the virtual memory limit.
One Idea was also using cgroups but in the OpenShift terminal it does not know the cgexec command.

Comment: Are you sure the OS ever frees unused pages? At the C level, if you don't use memory anymore, you free it, and the OS is back in charge of that memory. I can see a VM like the Java JVM or Python internally garbage-collecting and hence returning memory to the OS, but I don't think Linux does this. If the system runs out of memory, the OOM killer may terminate the process that uses most memory, which seems to happen to you. Maybe add the language your code is written in, to get better answers. I'd still check for resource leaks.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the program is coded in C++. Compilations for Windows do not seem to have this memory issue as well as the same compilation used for RHEL running on SLES. Not used memory is normally freed by our program but RHEL does not seem to release it. Our developers try now an approach calling malloc_trim() on the operating system which still seems like a workaround.